# How to change a TextView using Button

Tags: android, button, textview

I am sorry if the question seems very obvious, but I'm a beginner and i want to figure out how Android works.

What I am trying to do is editing a small virtual pad with two buttons (1 & 2).

Is it possible to change a `TextView` that is supposed to display what the user has typed by using setOnClickButton() inside the onCreate() method?

I am asking that because I've read in an other stackoverflow subject that the onCreate() method creates the activity once and for all and that it isn't possible to update it multiple times by introducing code inside the onCreate() method.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
Button button2;

public void arrayToString(ArrayList<String> toto, String tota){
    for (String s : toto)
    {
        tota += s + " ";
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<String> displayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String displayString = "";


    final TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.screen1);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);


    button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            displayList.add("1");
            arrayToString(displayList,displayString);
            displayTextView.setText(displayString);
        }    
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            displayList.add("2");
            arrayToString(displayList,displayString);
            displayTextView.setText(displayString);
        }    
    });  
}
}
```

Thanks again,

Comment: It can be done. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, it' possible. `onClick` listener will be called every time when you click on button.

Comment: Yes, actually my buttons doesn't respond when the users presses them and I can't figure out why...

Comment: Maybe its a problem from the activity_main.xml layout file. Probably you have some transparent layouts on top of the buttons. Did you put some logs inside onClick?

Comment: post the xml file of 'activity_main.xml'

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a problem with the LinearLayout containing the textView as you suggested...I thought it was the Textviews'text that wasn't displayed but actually it was the whole LinearLayout that wasn't visible because of the android:layout_height

Comment: Accept an answer if you think it has helped. And upvote if you think it deserves it.

Comment: Pleased to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, the OnClickListener "**LISTENS**" for clicks. So every time the button is clicked, the code inside the onClick() will be executed. So, that displayTextView.setText(displayString) will be run **every time you press the button**

Comment: will the new text of the textView be displayed on the running Activity or do I need to "refresh" it by creating the Activity with onCreat() again?

Comment: no, you dont need to call all that. the code you posted will refresh everytime you click.so, no need to 'refresh'

Answer (score 0):

Your code its OK. You defined two Buttons and set OnClickListener for each of them. The code is executed when you press the buttons. The code inside the onClickListener has nothing to do with the definition of onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    public String arrayToString(ArrayList<String> toto){
        String tota = "";
        for (String s : toto)
        {
            tota += s + " ";
        }
        retrun tota;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> displayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String displayString = "";


        final TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.screen1);

       button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
       button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);


button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        displayList.add("1");
        displayString = arrayToString(displayList);
        displayTextView.setText(displayString);
    }    
});

button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        displayList.add("2");
        displayString = arrayToString(displayList);
        displayTextView.setText(displayString);
    }    
});




}
}
```